# Springboot Problem : At least one JPA metamodel must be present

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm setting up a new project which is springboothibernate and used oracle db. but getting this problem when run project.

### this is my main.

```
package com.springboot.XCS60;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import 
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;

import com.springboot.XCS60.service.OpsEvidenceInService;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class BackendCheckForKeepApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BackendCheckForKeepApplication.class, 
 args);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add code useful for your question and please written it? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: OK, I have already added the problem as below, Could you please help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: Hey please add them in this question... you can edit it and remove the answers that you added. thank you.

Comment: Are you using persitence within your application? because the if you remove the dependecy called <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>  then your code will run ...

Comment: yes , I must use to mapping the oracle db entity, or Do you have a new way to do that ?

Comment: Using Oracle you can see this link as an example https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-oracle-example/

Comment: You even can download the code directly. it's at the ending of web site. if you have questions. let me know it. kind regards.